# Remove character from string in VB6

Tags: string, vb6

I have some strings (file paths) that sometimes have randomly placed line breaks (CRLF) inside of them that I have to remove. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Replace(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241892(v=VS.60).aspx) function.

```
someVariable = Replace(someVariable, vbNewLine, "")
```

Comment: +1 Although you have linked to the VB.Net 2005 documentation. I took the liberty of editing your post to link to the VB6 documentation.

Answer (score 6):

`Replace$()` replaces;

```
path = Replace$(path, vbcrlf, "")
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Replace$ function with a dollar sign.

Comment: @MatsT, the `$` signifies that the function returns a string. It is more exact to use the `$`, `&`, `%`, and `#` symbols on variables and functions.

Comment: It's also an optimization for some (but not replace()) string funcs http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#variant

Comment: I was confused because the documentation mentions separate functions for other functions such as LCase$/LCase and Trim$/Trim, but not for Replace. Why is it not an optimization for Replace?

Comment: VB6 was meant as a transitional product, but sadly was the last of its kind.  When a number of things (Split, Replace for example) were added to VBScript some of the code from there seems to have simply been grafted on when VB6 was rushed out the door.  That may be why the VB6 docs talk about the FSO and RegEx object so much and we never got native I/O streams in VB.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all CRLFs in your string.

```
strFileName = Replace(strFileName, vbNewLine, "")
```

Here is a function you can put in a helper module:

```
Public Function CleanFilePath(FilePath As String) As String
    Return Replace(FilePath, vbNewLine, "")
End Function
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, here is a helper subroutine to modify the string itself. This is not standard practice in newer languages, though.

```
Public Sub CleanFilePath(ByRef FilePath As String)
    FilePath = Replace(FilePath, vbNewLine, "")
End Sub
```

Comment: If I would make a helper function it makes more sense to just fix the path and not return anything though, or?

Comment: You mean pass the string itself `ByRef` and modify it? You could, but it is more standard practice with newer languages to return a value.

Comment: Agree that it is standard practice, but why is that exactly? Isn't it more optimized to pass along references instead of creating new objects?